# API oauth2 which grant type should I choose

Tags: api, security, mobile, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a personal project composed of an API and 4 clients (web, android, iOS, windows phone).

I'm using django-rest-framework and oauth2 toolkit on the API side and I wonder which grant_type would be more suitable in my situation.

I read somewhere that the implicit grant_type is appropriate for working with mobile clients.

I'm currently using the resource owner password credentials system.

My current workflow is:

- The user creates an account on the API registration page (http://mysite/api/register) then gets redirected on the web client.
- The user have to authenticate himself on the API from the web client (the secret and client ID are store in the web client). If the authentication is successful the access_token and refresh_token are both stored in the user session.
- Each time the user want to access a page I verify if he is authenticated by requesting the API using his access_token. If the request fails, I retry with the refresh_token. If it's fails again I redirect the user on the auth page.
- The user can use the API on a mobile client with the same account without extra manipulations (the secret and client ID are store in a secure location ex. share preferences or keychain)

I like this workflow, it's simple and convenient for the user: he registers once and can use all the clients and I get a perfect separation between the logic (API) and the UI (client). But I'm worried about the security of this system. I don't want to expose my users to threats. Do you guys have any thoughts, recommendations, suggestions?

You help in this matters would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using any social OAuth or just your own implementation? Does the client-server  communication happens over `https` or naked `http`?

Comment: I'm using a django package "django-oauth-toolkit" which is the officially supported implementation of oauth2 for the django-rest-framework. All the client-server communication happens over https.